# Generating identifier for new objects

Tags: java, object, oop, counter

I'm looking to implement identifier generator for all new objects created and assign value to them. What am I missing in the below code?

```
public abstract class Figure {

    private static int counter = 0;

    private int number;
   

    public Figure() {
    }

    public static Square createSquare(double a) {
        return new Square(a);
    }
 

    public static int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public static void setCounter(int counter) {
        Figure.counter = counter;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number = ++Figure.counter;
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you please clean up the code from irrelevant fields and methods and provide your current version of the factory? And where exactly is the id field?

Comment: If you give us all the necessary code with no extra code, we might have a chance.

Comment: how is this related to a factory design?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post. By posting on Stack Overflow, you’ve granted Stack Exchange the rights to the content you post under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 licence](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), regardless of any changes you may make. Vandalizing your posts will result in the edit being reverted, and continuous vandalism may lead to your post being [locked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts)

Comment: Understood, Cow. I submitted request to Support to delete this post as I really need to make it happen. Would you be able to help please?

Comment: If this is a homework question, please read [I've rethought my question about a homework assignment—why can't I get it deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403802)

Answer (score 1):

You should set the *number* in the static method invocation.

```java
public static Rectangle createRectangle(double a, double b) {
  Figure fg = new Rectangle(a, b);
  fg.number = ++counter;
  return fg;
}

public int getNumber() {
  return number;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just declare `private int number=0;` and set number in the factory method?

Answer (score 1):

First, remove **setCounter** method, as it's going to change the private state of the class.

Second, **getNumber** method should just return **this.number**. At the moment, whenever the method is called, your number is incremented.

Third, assign the value to the number in the **Figure** constructor:

> this.number = ++counter;

I suppose Square, Circle and Rectangle extend the Figure, so they will call super constructor and will get their number set.

Also, it's better to have a separate class for objects generation, if we are talking about the [factory design pattern](https://www.gofpattern.com/creational/patterns/factory-method-pattern.php).

Comment: @kotson, well, you can create a protected method for the Figure class:  protected void assignId() {  this.number = counter++; }, and call this method from your 'factory methods' after actual object creation. In this case your Figure constructor should remain empty. Another way is to add a boolean parameter to the constructor, explicitly specifying if the call goes from the 'factory method'.